# Communication with Arduino using Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, arduino

This is the first time I'm communicating with Arduino using my computer. I use Ubuntu 14.04. This is the C program for writing to the file. The Arduino shows up ttyACM0.

While compiling using gcc the compiler shows an error saying:

> Segmentation fault(core dumped)

How do I rectify this error.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char data[] = {'f','b','r'};  //Random data we want to send
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0","w");  //Opening device file
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    fprintf(file,"%c",data[i]); //Writing to the file
    fprintf(file,"%c",','); //To separate digits
    sleep(1);
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Pardon my ignorance. I tried researching on it. Couldn't make it work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It does not look like a `c++` code. why tag then?

Comment: Here's a thought - you could try debugging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// the following code:
//  compiles cleanly
//  performs appropriate error checking
//  has proper return statement

#include <unistd.h> // sleep()
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen(), fclose(), fprintf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE

int main()
{
    char data[] = {'f','b','r'};  //Random data we want to send
    FILE *file;
    if( NULL == (file = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0","w") ) )  //Opening device file
    { // then fopen failed
        perror("fopen failed for ttyACM0" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        if( 0 >= fprintf(file,"%c",data[i]) ) //Writing to the file
        { // fprintf failed
            perror("fprintf data failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fprintf successful for data

        if( 0 >= fprintf(file,"%c",',') ) //To separate digits
        { // then, fprintf failed
            perror( "fprintf for comma failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fprintf successful for comma

        sleep(1);
    } // end for
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: this code, with the proper error checking, should tell the OP, via stderr, the source of the problem.

Comment: appaently "fopen failed for ttyACM0: Access denied"

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a `NULL` return from the `fopen()` that `NULL` is being passed to `fprintf()` which is expecting a valid FILE* and messing up causing the `SEGV`.

If you use `fopen` you should check what it returns so you can give the user a something more useful than "segmentation fault".

The probable cause of the `fopen()` failure is you don't have permission to play with the serial port.

Normally you need the group `dialout` to be able to access the serial port.

As root do:

`usermod -a -G dialout`*yourusername*

Then log out and back in so you get the new group.

Consider using minicom or microcom (on any of the several other serial terminal programs) to access the serial port instead of writing your own.

I also suggest you have the Arduino send a hello message when it boots up so you can be sure you have the right baud rate etc...

Comment: Probably the cause of `fopen` failure but not the cause of the SIGSEGV.

Comment: So you should also mention that it's wrong to ignore the result of `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not put any success check on the return value of `fopen("/dev/ttyACM0","w");`. In case `fopen()` fails, using `file` further is undefined behavior, causing segmentation fault. Do something like

```
file = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0","w");  //Opening device file
if (file)
{
        //do something with file
}
else
     return 0;
```

Also, add a `return 0` before ending `main()`.

Comment: what is the `else` for? why don't you return an error code instead of `0`?

Comment: @iharob else part says _file opening has failed. don't use the file pointer_. and about the return value, there is nothing standard, you can use any value that is meaningful to you. :-)

Comment: but returning `0` from main means no error happened, and the `else` is not needed, you can return `0` if `file != NULL` and some value by default.

Comment: @iharob well, that depends. Mostly, in case of APIs, you're very right. BUt IMO, failing to `fopen()` usually should not signify the failure of `main()`. An error message would suffice.

Comment: I don't disagree with you.

Comment: Probably in the else branch a call to "perror()" could be informative,  error return should be `EXIT_FAILURE` (from <stdlib.h> defined as 1 on linux), or in non-protable code like this some platform specific convention, on linux it's low positive integers for error codes,

Answer (score 0):

On failure `fopen` returns `NULL`, so you are potentially dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, the correct way of doing that, is checking the result of `fopen`. I would however suggest low level IO for this kind of thing something like

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char data[] = {'f','b','r'};  //Random data we want to send
    int fd;
    int i;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_WRONLY);  //Opening device file
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("cannot open /dev/ttyACM0");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        write(fd, &(data[i]), 1);
        write(fd, ",", 1);

        sleep(1);
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

on error `open` returns a special value `-1` so you should abort writing to it.

I'm pretty sure in your case there will be a `permission denied` error, since normally the `/dev/tty*` belong to group `dialout` and they have group write permission by default, but since probably your user doesn't belong to that group you don't have write access to `/dev/ttyACM0`.